# Google wallet add payment method in webview results in a blank page, android

Tags: android, android-pay

So, everything works fine until I want to add payment method. Upon clicking I noticed the link opens it in the web browser, instead of the webview and results in a blank page. Can anyone shed light on this?

If I am using the my web browser it works perfectly, but if it is on a mobile device, it results in the blank page.

Thanks